# Sum of random list numbers after 1st negative number

Tags: python, list, numbers

```py
import random

def mainlist(list, size, min, max):
    for i in range(size):
        list.append(random.randint(min, max))
    print(list)

def counterlist(list):
    for i in list:
        if i<0:
            x=sum(list[(list.index(i)+1):])
            print('Reqemlerin cemi:', x)
            break
       
     
list = []
mainlist(list, 10, -10, 30)
counterlist(list)
```

I need to calculate sum of numbers after 1st negative number in this random list, did it in second function but want to know is there way not using the `sum()` function?

Comment: You can always iterate over the rest of the elements in the list, and keep adding values of those elements. if you do not want to use `sum` function

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: I already tried to iterate elements and add them values but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

lst = [random.randint(-10, 30) for _ in range(10)]
print(sum(lst[next(i for i, n in enumerate(lst) if n < 0) + 1:]))
```

First you generate the list `lst`. Then, you iterate over your list and you find the first negative element with `next(i for i, n in enumerate(lst) if n < 0)`. Finally, you compute the sum of the portion of the list you're interested about.

If you really don't want to use `sum` but keep things concise (and you're using python >= 3.8):

```
import random

lst = [random.randint(-10, 30) for _ in range(10)]
s = 0
print([s := s + x for x in lst[next(i for i, n in enumerate(lst) if n < 0) + 1:]][-1])
```

Comment: I tried your first solution, it crashed (saying `StopIteration`).

Comment: Your second solution has the same problem. Also, it's not clear why you've replaced their `index` call with `enumerate`, which is longer code and makes it slower.

Comment: Who can read that. I think the most importand aspect of programming is clarity, and this is defenitly not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly using an iterator makes it nicer and more efficient:

```
def counterlist(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    for i in it:
        if i < 0:
            print('Reqemlerin cemi:', sum(it))
```

No idea why you wouldn't want to use the `sum` function, that's absolutely the right and best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a negative value in the list, and with a test list "a":

```
a = [1,2,3,-7,2,3,4,-1,23,3]
sum(a[(a.index([i for i in a if i < 0][0]) + 1):])
```

Evaluates to 34 as expected.  Could also add a try/except IndexError with a simple sum to catch if there's no negative value.

Edit: updated the index for the search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can iterate over the elements of the list and keep adding them to some var which would store your result. But what for? `sum` approach is much more clear and python-ish.

Also, don't use `list` as a list name, it's a reserved word.

```
# After you find a first negative number (at i position)
j = i + 1
elements_sum = 0
while j < len(list):
    elements_sum += list[j]
    j += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as the marked answer, but just to know how to make use of numpy, being sure there is a negative number in the list.

Sample list: `lst = [12, 2, -3, 4, 5, 10, 100]`

You can get your result using `np.cumsum`:

```
import numpy as np

np_lst = np.array(lst)
cum_sum = np.cumsum(np_lst)
res = cum_sum[-1] - cum_sum[np_lst<0][0]
res #=> 119
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a reserved keyword. Secondly, make your loop as follows:

```
for index, x in enumerate(list_):
    if x < 0:
        sum_ = sum(list_[(index + 1):])
        print('Reqemlerin cemi:', sum_)
        break
```

That way, you don't need to find a value.

At last if you don't want to use `sum`

```
found_negative = false
sum_ = 0
for x in list_:
    if found_negative:
        sum_ += x
    elif x < 0:
        found_negative = true
        
print('Reqemlerin cemi:', sum_)
```